# Can Views Control other views?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am implementing my own basic MVC framework and I have a graph-like view which shows a bunch of points like a scatter graph. Here is a simplified version:

```
public class GraphView extends View 
{
    private List<Point2D> points;

    //view code

    public void setPoint(int index, float x, float y)
    {
        points.get(index).setLocation(x,y);
    }

    public int getNumPoints()
    {
        return points.size();
    }
}
```

I also have a view which uses this view as a subview with some extra controls, one of which is a button which randomizes the points on the graph view.

```
public class GraphControlsView extends View 
{
    private GraphView graph;
    private JButton randomizeButton;

    //view code

    //called by the button
    public void randomize()
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < graph.getNumPoints();i++)
         {
             graph.setPoint(i,Math.random(),Math.random());
         }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if this is the right place for the logic to randomize the points on the graph view. It seems like I am mixing the responsibilities of the view and controller and that this logic should reside in a controller. However, if I moved the logic into a controller and simply had a button listener, a controller could use that button to do things that it isn't intended for despite it having a "Randomize" label on it.

So in short, should the GraphControlsView directly control it's GraphView subview? Or should there be a controller which listens to the GraphControlsView and sets points on the GraphView?

Comment: You could take a look at how the android adapter handles it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Comment: Not sure but are you looking for MVP pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

When applying the MVC Model, you should keep all user input processing in the model. The view is only concern with output display and the user interface while the model deals with the 'physics' of the program. The controller relays data between the two and keeps them distinct. This way you have a better separation of concerns.
Keeping this in mind, your point randomization logic should be implemented in the Model class. The result is then relayed to the view of the graph where it is displayed.

As for the button executing beyond what is desired, this  technically should not happen. Assuming each button is assigned to a specific task, it should have its own action command. when implementing the action listener, you need to make sure you code a conditional to execute the desired code **only** if the event's set action command is the one assigned to the corresponding button. You can set the action command by calling the setActionCommand() method of the JButton. You can check for it by the action listener by calling the getActionCommand() method of the Event argument of the actionPerformed() method.

Let me know if you need more clarifications.